# Understanding the WordPress template hierarchy

Tags: theme-development, template-hierarchy

I watched a lot of courses about Wordpress Development on Udemy. Also I've almost finished my "Wordpress Development" track on Teamtreehouse, but I can't understand one simple thing, because one course a little bit contradicts another.

My question is about `page.php`, `content.php` and `single.php`. What is the best practice to use these files?

For example, I need to create a portfolio site. As I understand, I need:

1. Create `page-portfolio.php` file that will be my main static page where I will show all the photos.
2. Create `content-portfolio.php` file that will be each photo's preview.
3. Create `single-portfolio.php` file that will be a singular post page for my photo.
4. After that in `page-portfolio.php` we need to create a `loop` and execute `get_template_part` function with `content` and `portfolio` as the parameteres. I mean `get_template_part( 'content', 'portfolio' )`.
5. In `single.php` we need to create a loop and execute `get_template_part( 'single', get_post_format() )` function. If our custom post has `portfolio` format, it will be worked perfectly.

Now when we go to our "Portfolio" page, the `page-portfolio.php` will be shown for us. On this `page-portfolio.php` we will have a lot of `content-portfolio.php` items (photos) and when we click on one of them the `single-portfolio.php` will be shown as a singular post page? Am I right? Is it good practice?

I saw a few themes that use only `content-slug.php` for the preview and for the singular post page. [Underscores](http://underscores.me/) uses this practice. They have one `content.php` for two cases. And in this file they choose what to show to the user with `if statement`. Something like this:

```
    if ( is_single() ) {
        the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title">', '</h1>' );
    } else {
        the_title( '<h2 class="entry-title"><a href="' . esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '" rel="bookmark">', '</a></h2>' );
    }
```

If it's a preview they show `h2` and if it's a singular post page they show `h1`. Why don't they create two separate files for this? Is it good practice to have a preview and a singular post page in one file?

Comment: It's more a preference issue for doing it various ways.  There is nothing wrong with your outlined approach.

Comment: not sure what you are meaning by "preview" in your question when the condition you are referring to is `is_single`? that is not a preview check.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A little preface here. I'm going to assume you know nothing of post types or templates since I'm unfamiliar with Underscores or the Teamtreehouse development track. Hopefully the below helps clear things up if not ask further in the comments.

WordPress starts with a few [built-in post types](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types#Default_Post_Types) that you're already familiar with:

- Posts ( post type slug: `page` )
- Pages ( post type slug: `post` )

They use [their own templates](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/), usually they go by the following:

- Posts

  - `home.php` or `index.php` is your archive page or list of Posts
  - `archive.php` is where everything else goes ( archives, categories, tags )
  - `single.php` is where your single content is going to be.
- Pages

  - `front-page.php` to assign a single pages content as your homepage.
  - `page.php` used for the default template of all pages
  - `page-{$slug}.php` which is used to target a specific page by their slug.

You could use the above with [normal loops](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop#Using_the_Loop) to display your content, you don't necessarily need to use things like [`get_template_part()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/) which is really just WordPress's version of [PHP `include()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php).

---

Now, what you're trying to do with Portfolio's you probably want to build your own [Custom Post Type](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types#Custom_Post_Types). These Custom Post Types use variations of the above templates:

- Portfolio ( Your Custom Post Type ) - `portfolio` will be the slug.

  - `archive-{post-type-slug}.php` is where your list of portfolio posts will be.

    - `archive.php` will be the fallback if WordPress can't find the above template.
    - `index.php` if there is no `archive.php` then WordPress will fallback to this template for display.
  - `single-{post-type-slug}.php` will be your single full portfolio post.

    - `single.php` will be the fallback if the above template isn't found.

You would switch out the `{post-type-slug}` in the above templates with your post type slug so in the end you would have:

- `archive-portfolio.php` and `single-portfolio.php`

Now as far as a static page for your post type you have a ton of options, none of which are right or wrong necessarily.

1) You could create an actual page for it, call it `page-portfolio.php` but then you would need to run a separate [`WP_Query()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) to pull your Portfolio posts because WordPress won't know to associate that `page` post type with you `portfolio` post type. Same issue with a global [Page Template](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/page-templates/#creating-custom-page-templates-for-global-use) but you wouldn't need to keep track of IDs or Slugs.

2) You could allow the user to assign a page to your post type. Similar to going to the admin panel `Settings -> Reading` and assigning a Front Page and Blog Page. You could save a page ID into the database and on your `archive-{post-type}.php` get the content of that page to display it.

I'm sure there are other ways, everybody has their preferred method.

---

I'm not against using the above method of using template parts to separate your content but I feel it's overly complicated for beginners when the simplified WordPress templates method is much easier to grasp.

Comment: you forgot `singular.php` as fallback for all single posts irregardless the post_type. (since [WP 4.3](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2015/07/06/singular-php-new-theme-template-in-wordpress-4-3/))

Comment: post_type archives with a separate `WP_Query()` are not best practice, due to the extra query on page load. you should not recommend that! Use the built in `has_archive` flag for CPTs and alter the main query with `pre_get_posts` filter

Comment: @iantsch Right, this isn't a 100% extensive guide to the template hierarchy, just a quick overview of the necessities. Where did I mention using using a `WP_Query` on an archive page? I mentioned using a `WP_Query` on a **page** template as you would need to pull in portfolio items. If you're using `archive-{$post-type}.php` you wouldn't need to use `has_archive` as that template will automatically pull in your specific post types posts.

Comment: i know… i just wanted to mention it. but you got the downvote for the static page part. a custom query where none is needed shouldn't be part of an answer.

Comment: That's fine. If someone wants pull custom content onto a post type archive, you either need to statically add it into the template or give the user a way to edit it themselves which can easily be done using the built in Pages. So you're either pulling that pages content ( and possible title, whatever more you have for custom pages ) into the `archive` template or pull the posts into your page template. They're both valid options and having multiple queries on a template is fairly common and not at all a bad thing.

Comment: I would put the `archive` page title and description into option fields and filter the output accordingly on the archives template. the options are autoloaded anyway (no extra query). that is (or should be) best practise for archives with custom content. **edit** they are valid code but not good solutions.

Comment: As @MarkKaplun told me:  _As the code on this site is example for other people to how to write proper code, we should put ourself to higher standard._

Comment: Your logic you'd have to build that additional functionality for each post type static page you have so you can save that data into the options table (along with cleanup upon deletion of said pages). How will you distinguish between pages you need and pages you don't? What if your pages are more complex than just titles and descriptions? You're adding redundant data to the database where there doesn't need to be and is thus inefficient. A more solid solution would be either a page template or allow the user to assign an ID ( such as Front Page / Blog Page ) and pull the page into the archive.

Comment: That's just additional functionality that overcomplicates a simple post type creation and is probably a tad out of reach for someone just starting out as OP implies in their question.

Comment: A page is something with so called static content per WordPress definition. You can always abstract the code, build a routine and do the stuff you just mentioned without code redundancies. If you want to show your portfolio, you got your archive. Use the template to show, filter the main query to manipulate and the options for custom variable data (like WordPress does too, e.g. you got all bloginfo data saved as option). You can store your complex data as options too. If you do it, do it right! Even if you start, try to do it the right and not the easiest way.

Comment: @iantsch You keep saying "the right way" but that's conjecture. We just disagree on how to do things - we both see each other's method as inefficient. This may be better as an open discussion in [The Loop](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6/the-loop) where multiple people could weigh in.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee +1 for that. :)